# How do I replace a broken halogen bulb in the recessed light in my bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, lighting, bulb

First, some pictures:

[image: one]

[image: two].

I can replace the bulbs in the rest of my apartment just fine but the ones in the bathroom have a special enclosure around them that I don't know how to open. The only logical place to open the enclosure seems to be the chrome ring at the bottom but I've had no success trying to pull and/or twist it.

Comment: Did you try to find a specification sheet from the manufacturer on the web (assuming there is enough info on the body of the unit)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that the bezel (the outer chrome trim ring) is attached to the locking mounting rods.(the coiled wire on outside of fixture)  You may need to open those rods, pull them up to 90degrees or more to the fixture and push them into the fixture body and the bezel will drop as the rods go in. It may also be connected to the bulb socket as well.

Comment: If that doesn't work, perhaps the bezel and lower white piece together separates from the body at the joint under your thumb. The flat metal tabs on either side could be some sort of locking or retaining mechanism that needs to be manipulated some way to gain a release.

Answer (score 0):

That chrome trim ring should be locked in position with a spring type device. all you would have to do is pull with some fair amount of pressure and that should come off. IF not try to push in the silver thing on the side of the can that is located under the long spring on the side. I dont know if thats its but usually the trim piec just gets pulled off and is spring loaded to hold it in place. After that the bulb is usually a gu19 base if it is a 3" can which it looks like it is...so it would be like a quarter clockwise turn i believe to unlock the bulb from the socket itself, after that just do the opposite to put the bulb and trim back as well. check out this pdf for installation instructions on a similar can

http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202600563/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=3%22+recessed+can&storeId=10051#more_info